# How do I make this IEnumerable loop generic?

Tags: c#, generics

I think this method could be converted into taking a generic. Then I can use it for any enumerable type. How do I make this generic?

```
private bool AreAnyInteractablesInThisList(
    IEnumerable<Interactable> Interactables, 
    Interactable InteractableToCheck)
{
    foreach (var Interactable in Interactables)
    {
        if (Interactable.GetInstanceID() == InteractableToCheck.GetInstanceID()) 
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: You cannot make this generic, because not every type has a method `GetInstanceID()`.

Comment: ..unless you add an interface or base class (to continue from above). Without knowing your code structure we can't answer this though. I'd also why? What do you want to make this generic? What do you hope to gain?

Comment: Hi Liam, I'd hope I could make this into a utility script. For example, I might have a class called 'Liam'. I'd also want to check if Liam is in my Liam list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd need to create an interface declaring the `GetInstanceID()` method:

```
public interface IInteractable
{
    int GetInstanceID(); // I guess it's an int, but you can change that accordingly
}
```

and then make the method generic with a constraint that the generic argument has to implement that interface:

```
private bool AreAnyInteractablesInThisList<T>(IEnumerable<T> Interactables, T InteractableToCheck) where T : IInteractable
{
    foreach (var Interactable in Interactables)
    {
        if (Interactable.GetInstanceID() == InteractableToCheck.GetInstanceID()) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Note that you can shorten the method to:

```
private bool AreAnyInteractablesInThisList<T>(IEnumerable<T> Interactables, T InteractableToCheck) where T : IInteractable
{
    // I cache this ID (assuming it was not changing with each call)
    int idToCheck = InteractableToCheck.GetInstanceID();
    return Interactables.Any(interactable => interactable.GetInstanceID() == idToCheck);
}
```